# How can I set TTL for DNS Caching with Delphi SOAP webservices?

Tags: web-services, delphi, caching, soap, dns

I have a Delphi Application accessing a web service on the Internet.
The provider of said service has now changed to a cloud based infrastructure and came to me with the following request:

"Please configure networkaddress.cache.ttl in the `file $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` as follows: `networkaddress.cache.ttl=60`"

Accordung to the web service provider this is necessary for the service to deliver correct results under all circumstances.
He has checked the connection of my appication and it appears to him that once started it sticks with the same IP-address.
Restarting the Applications did solve this for once.

I have been importing the WSDL using the wizard provided by the IDE so I am using an instance of THTTPRIO to access the web service.
The THTTPRIO-instance is created in FormCreate() of the main form.
The Application is running 24/7 and accesses several methods of the web service regularly.

Does the Delphi SOAP framwork use DNS caching at all?
If yes, is there a similar property like `networkaddress.cache.ttl` in Java?

Is there a good workaround for the issue (e.g. reinstancing the wrapper class just before every call to the service instead of only once in `FormCreate`)?

**EDIT:**
The Application is compiled using Delphi 10.1. Berlin (originally developed with Delphi XE7). It is running on an Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework for delphi? Which OS is it?

Comment: I am using the SOAP framework that comes with Delphi (Delphi 10.1 Berlin Enterprise ATM). Its running on Windows 7.

Comment: Which platform? (Answer might be OS-dependent)

Comment: It's Windows 7 (just added this to the question).

Answer (score 1):

Have you found **DnsFlushResolverCache**?

> In order to clear DNS resolver cache like what IPCONFIG /flushdns
>   does, programmatically:
>
> Requires dnsapi.dll which requires Win2000 or later. As usual, MS does
>   not document the API

Source: http://brannockdevice.blogspot.de/2006/04/winxp-flushing-dns-programatically.html

Comment: Thanks! This may come in handy if a simple reconnect turns out to be not enough...

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging into the source code a little and I believe I found an answer.
The Delphi SOAP framwork doesn't seem to do any DNS caching on its own.
It's just that the connection to the web service is done with the first request via the Windows `InternetConnect()` function and the resulting handle ist stored and reused from then on.

Here's a little more background information on this:

The `THTTPRIO` class communicates with the web service through an instance of `THTTPReqResp`:

```
property HTTPWebNode: THTTPReqResp read GetHTTPWebNode write SetHTTPWebNode;
```

`THTTPReqResp` calls the `Connect()` method before every request which again uses a WinApi function to estabish a connection and stores the resulting handle in a field:

```
FInetConnect := InternetConnect(FInetRoot, PChar(FURLHost), FURLPort, PChar(FUserName), PChar(FPassword), INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NativeUInt(Self));
```

But - the `Connect()` method only does this if it is not already connected - the following code is found just at the beginning of the `Connect()` method:

```
if (FConnected) then
  Exit;
```

By doing so the connection just stays open from the first request on.
Following requests are simply using the stored handle from `InetConnect`.

For my problem with the cloud service it should be sufficient to create my own instance of `THTTPRIO` and pass it to the function returning the web service interface:

```
RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
FM := GetFleetManagerAPISoap(FALSE, '', RIO);
```

Then I will just disconnect each time before calling any web service function:

```
RIO.HTTPWebNode.Connect(FALSE);
```

In theory that should finally lead to a fresh connection via `InternetConnect()` and hopefully my problem will be solved.
(Still have to test this, though)

Answer (score -2):

I think that you can set it globally in Windows registry.

Open regedit.exe and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters.
```

In the right pane, add the following value:

Name: DefaultTTL,
Type: REG_DWORD,
Valid Range: 1-255

Restar the computer.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957530.aspx

Comment: From what I read this TTL corresponds to TCPIP network packages. But `networkaddress.cache.ttl` in Java seems to influence DNS caching instead: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html#nct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html#nct)

Comment: @AndreasWieland What about this other key? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services \DNSCache\Parameters 

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775464(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: If Windows is the the culprit here this might help - though the technet article you are linking to only mentions Windows Server OSs - not Windows 7 ... I'll look and see if there is a not too cumbersome method to test this...